# Tab button is not working in form text fields

Tags: javascript, tabs, textfield

i have a form in which i am using 4 textfields.

textfield1
textfield2
textfield3
textfield4

i am calling a function on "onpress" event on textfield2 and textfield3 for checking only integer values. the function is given below.

```
function checkIntnumber(obj,event){
var unicode=event.charCode? event.charCode : event.keyCode
if((unicode==37 || unicode==39 || unicode==35 || unicode==36 || unicode==46)   
     &&  event.which==0) {//if the key isn't the (BackSpace/Left Arrow/Right  
   Arrow/Delete/Home/End) key (which we should allow)
        return true;
} else if(unicode!=8) {
         if (unicode>=48 && unicode<=57) { //if a number 
            return true; //enable key press
        } else {
            return false; //disable key press
        }
}
 }
```

now then i move from textfield1 to textfield2 using tab key this is working fine but tab key is not working to move from textfield2 to textfield3 or textfield3 to textfield4. this problem is occuring in mozilla firefox only. please help me.
thanks

EDIT: code from the comment under the answer -

```
<input type="text" name="from" id="from" style="width:50px;"
       onkeypress="hideRateDiv();return checkIntnumber(this,event)"/>
- <input type="text" name="to" id="to" style="width:50px;"
       onkeypress="hideRateDiv();return checkIntnumber(this,event)" tabindex="2"/>
```

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with tabindex rather than the event binding...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex check this link out

Comment: Your code only includes two fields, yet you said you had a problem with moving to the third and fourth fields. Would you post your complete HTML code from `<form>` to `</form>`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test for the code that corresponds to the tab key (`9`) and return true.

EDIT: Sorry, just saw Christian's comment and read the question a bit more carefully. There could be a tabindex issue, but there shouldn't be if the four fields are defined right after each other in your source HTML. But given that the code you posted doesn't seem to allow the tab key I don't understand how tabbing would work between your field 1 and 2 - it shouldn't work between any of them.

Can you please post the HTML for those fields and show how you assign the keypress event?

Comment: <input type="text" name="from" id="from" style="width:50px;" onkeypress="hideRateDiv();return checkIntnumber(this,event)"/>                                - <input type="text" name="to" id="to" style="width:50px;" onkeypress="hideRateDiv();return checkIntnumber(this,event)" tabindex="2"/>

Comment: can anyone tell me the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

`if((unicode==37 || unicode==39 || unicode==35 || unicode==36 || unicode==46 || unicode==9) &&  event.which==0)`  Change the if condition like this, keycode for tab also (that is 9)